# Vector image from AI to AE

Tags: video

I've ben watching tons of videos and read a lot of forums about this problem, but still cant find the solution...

The thing is that everybody says to put every object on different layers and then import the file like Footage... merged layers... then convert to layerd comp or create shapes from layers and so on... but my images are still blurry, even though i klick the button to continuosly rasterize.

this makes me crazy

please for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that After Effects is a raster (meaning a grid of pixels, as opposed to vector, and as opposed to Haile Selassie, Lion of Judah) application, like Photoshop. It can use vectors, but the output will always be a raster. So the ultimate resolution of your text depends on the resolution of your comp. So while clicking the continuous rasterisation will give you the smoothest results, the results will be limited to the pixel grid of your comp.

[image]

So you have to design with the resolution of your finished product in mind, which sets a lower limit on the size of elements like text. Think that's bad? Try designing for standard definition interlaced video designed to be distributed on VHS. You kids don't know how good you gots it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're zoomed in 2400%. If you view at 100% it should look smooth. I think the "blur" is just anti-aliasing.